# Command Line Commands in C#

Tags: c#

I want to run a few Windows programs from C#. How would I do this? From what I've been looking up, it has something to do with System.Diagnostics.Process 's start method

Would I just do using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process;
```

and then type

```
start("Command to be executed");
```

or am I looking at this problem incorrectly?

New to C#.

Comment: Did you check [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: You seem to have made it all the way to the answer, but didn't actually try implementing it. Why not?

Comment: Because typing "start" gives me a squiggly line.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Did you look through the methods/properties in `Process` in intellisense, or on the documentation for that class?  That's always a good place to start when you want to know more about a type.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments it seems that you are unfamiliar with <strike>object-oriented programming</strike> namespaces and classes. Let's break it down.

`Process` is a class, part of the .NET framework. `Process` has has a collection of methods, some of them being `static` methods. `Start` is one of those static methods. There are two pieces necessary in order for you to use `Process.Start`:

1. The compiler needs to know what `Process` is. You can give that info to the compiler by adding `using System.Diagnostics;` to the top of your class file. This tells the compiler to look for classes in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, which is where `Process` lives.
2. You need to explicitly tell the compiler that you're calling a method named `Start` *that is part of the process class*. You can do this by using `Process.Start()`. Or in your case, `Process.Start("Command to be executed");`

There are two reasons why you CANNOT just type `start("Command to be executed")`:

1. `start`, with a lowercase "s", is not the same as `Start` with an uppercase "S". C# is a case-sensitive language.
2. If you don't prepend your method call with a particular class name, the compiler looks in your own class for that method, and when it doesn't find one, it tells you about it.

Comment: It occurs to me now that nothing in my answer has anything to do with object-oriented programming, but rather just namespaces and classes. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: essentially the "Command to be executed" part is what you would type in the command prompt. For example:

```
Process.Start("C:\Programs\programFile.exe",
              "/arg1='This is an argument' -arg2=anotherArgument someOtherArgument");
```

The entry point of your program (which file is located at "C:\Programs\programFile.exe") would receive the following argument list in its main method:

```
args[0] = "/arg1='This is an argument'"
args[1] = "-arg2=anotherArgument"
args[2] = "someOtherArgument"
```

This way of passing parameters as a command line is obviously not the greatest to format, but it does the job all the time.

Comment: Except you shouldn't pass arguments to the executable like that. Use the appropriate overload of Start.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Start Internet Explorer. Defaults to the home page.
Process.Start("IExplore.exe");

// Display the contents of the favorites folder in the browser.
Process.Start(myFavoritesPath);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)